Firestore Write from Beam
Is it possible to write to 2 different firestore databases from the same beam Job ? One database is the 'default' and the other being a different one.
When building the beam pipeline, it is picking the default firestore database if we are not specifying anything in the pipeline options. If I specify a different database before build, then only it is getting considered. So I am assuming the pipeline build is bound for only one firestore DB.

It looks like you are correct as of Beam 2.57.0.  This is certainly an oversight; I filed an issue.  It probably wouldn't be too hard to fix; it just involves plumbing the parameter through the builders.
